# Is there possibillity to call constructor inside Container.get() in typedi?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jasmine

I am using typedi with node.js

I wonder if I could do something like that

```
const obj = Container.get(MyObj(creds));
```

istead of

```
const obj = new MyObj(creds);
```

I need that to use because of jasmine unit testing. I need the same object.

How should I do it to get the same object inside my unit test?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service()
class MyObj {

    @Inject("creds")
    creds: any;

}
```

Then you can inject like this:

```
Container.set("creds", creds);
const obj = Container.get(MyObj);
console.log(obj.creds);
```